# Loading Bootstrap modal in SQL while

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following function

```
function articlesList($limit) { ?>
 <div class="table-responsive rounded mb-20">
 <table class="table table-striped table-theme">
    <thead>
         <tr>
             <th style="width: 5%;" class="text-center border-right">ID</th>
             <th style="width: 10%;" class="text-center">Image</th>
             <th style="width: 50%;">Name</th>
             <th style="width: 20%;">Date</th>
             <th style="width: 15%;" class="text-center">Actions</th>
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
 <?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY ID DESC";
 $items = mysql_query($sql);
 while ($art = mysql_fetch_array($items)) { 
 $id = "$art[ID]"; ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center border-right"><?=$art[ID]?></td>
        <td class="text-center"><img src="../media/articles/<?=$art[image]?>" class="img-bordered-theme" width="45" height="45"></td>
        <td><?=$art[name]?></td>
        <td><?=$art[date]?></td>
        <td class="text-center">
        <a href="?act=edit&amp;id=<?=$art[ID]?>" class="btn btn-success btn-sm rounded" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm rounded" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".remove_<?=$art[ID]?>" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
     <!-- Start MODAL EVENTS -->
     <div class="remove_<?=$art[ID]?> modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
         <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" style="margin-top: 200px;">
             <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Remove article</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body"><p>Are you sure you want to remove the article <b><?=$art[name]?></b>?</p></div>
                 <div class="modal-footer">
                     <form name="input" action="?act=remove" method="post">
                         <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$art[ID]?>">
                         <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?=$art[name]?>">
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
                     </form>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
     <!-- End MODAL EVENTS -->
 <?php } ?>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 </div>
 <?php } //function
```

My problem is with the modal box. The loading works well, all variables is passed but something is happened when the modal is opened.

Something like this: [image]

The buttons can't be pressed, I can't close the box or do anything else.

After some tests, if I  put the modal code to the bottom of the while but outside of this, the modal works great. But the variables can't be passed anymore.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the modal outside the loop, you can pass the values to modal with [BS modal event function](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)

Add a `data-attribute` to modal trigger button e.g `data-id="<?=$art[ID]?>"` and remove `<?=$art[ID]?>` from `data-target`

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm rounded" data-id="<?=$art[ID]?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".remove" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
```

and the second variable you have to pass to the modal is `<?=$art[name]?>`, add another `data-attribute` to it too e.g `data-value="<?=$art[ID]?>"`

```
<td><span class="name" data-value="<?=$art[ID]?>"><?=$art[name]?></span></td>
```

Note: you can add `data-value="<?=$art[ID]?>"` to any on-page element and pass it to modal.

Now the modal HTML (outside the loop) will be
Note: I added `<span class="Mname"></span>` in modal to show the name, and added `id's` to input to pass the value

```
<!-- Start MODAL EVENTS -->
<div class="remove modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" style="margin-top: 200px;">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Remove article</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Are you sure you want to remove the article <b><span class="pname"></span></b> ?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <form name="input" action="?act=remove" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="pid" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="name" id="pname" value="">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End MODAL EVENTS -->
```

The BS Modal event listener script will be

```
$(document).ready(function(){ //Dom Ready
    $('.remove').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) { //Show event listener
        //Fetch val from modal button data-attribute
        var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
        //fetch name which match the data-attribute val of modal button
        var name = $('.name[data-value="' + id +'"]').html();
        //you can pass any on page variable or information to modal like this by creating more variables like `var name`
        //Now Pass it to modal
        $(".pname").html(name); 
        $("#pid").val(id);
        $("#pname").val(name);
    });
});
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/0r39h8cm/)